# How to auto generate divs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, design-patterns

I made a basic javascript code so you can poke divs with you mouse.

Unfortunately I have to add them manualy but i wanna add so much of them with a pattern.
First i decided to use grid but i guessed it wont work because divs (which i call them squares from now on :D) can change their position.

So I was about to ask, how can I create a javascript code that i can spawn them until they fill the screen.

Also i have another question which is realted to this project, How can i make these squares just decors. I mean by decors i dont want them to effect the webside at all, when the blocks goes out of the screen the body starts to expend, is there any way to avoid that?

(Also it will be better if you make the snippet full screen!)

EDIT: I put the refresh-button on the top left on the main div so you can draw squares by clicking it!

```js
let mouse = {
    speedX: 0,
    speedY: 0,
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0,
    movement: 0,
    speed: 0
  }
  
  //on mousemove update the moouse object
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouse.speedX = e.movementX;
    mouse.speedY = e.movementY
    mouse.posX = e.pageX;
    mouse.posY = e.pageY;
  }
  
  //refresh the mouse movement and speed every 100ms
  setInterval(() => {
    mouse.movement =
      Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouse.speedX, 2) + Math.pow(mouse.speedY, 2));
    mouse.speed = mouse.movement * 10;
  }, 100);
  
  //add a square div in parent element
  function addSquare(parent) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add("square")
    parent.appendChild(newDiv)
    return newDiv;
  }
  
  //add squares in the parent element filling the available size
  //gap is the space between squares, size is the edge of the square
  //if skipbefore is false it will begin to draw the next square also if it won't fit entirely
  function addSquares(parent, gap, size, skipbefore = true) {
  
    const squares = [];
  
    let rect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
    const availableWidth = rect.width;
    const availableHeight = rect.height;
  
    let top = 100;
    while (top < availableHeight) {
      let left = 0;
      if (skipbefore && top + size > availableHeight)
        break;
      while (left < availableWidth) {
        if (skipbefore && left + size > availableWidth)
          break;
        const square = addSquare(parent);
        square.style.left = `${left}px`;
        square.style.top = `${top}px`;
        squares.push(square);
        left += gap + size;
      }
      top += gap + size;
    }
  
    return squares;
  }
  
  //onmoveover event handler
  const squareOnMouseOver = (event) => {
    const element = event.target;
  
    const y = mouse.speedY;
    const x = mouse.speedX;
  
    const rad = Math.atan2(y, x);
    yAxis = mouse.movement * Math.sin(rad);
    xAxis = mouse.movement * Math.cos(rad);
  
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  
    const left = Math.round(rect.x + xAxis * 3);
    const top = Math.round(rect.y + yAxis * 3);
  
    element.style.left = `${left}px`;
    element.style.top = `${top}px`;
    const o = rad * (180 / Math.PI);
    element.style.transform = `rotate(${o}deg)`;
  }
  
  //resets the .target parent and redraw the squares inside it
  function drawSquares() {
  
    const parent = document.querySelector('.target');
    parent.innerHTML = '';
    const squares = addSquares(parent, 25, 75);
  
    const colors = [
      'lightcoral',
      'bisque',
      'aquamarine',
      'cadetblue',
      'greenyellow',
      'yellowgreen'
    ];
  
    squares.forEach(square => {
      const iColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length - 1));
      const color = colors[iColor];
      square.style.background = color;
      square.addEventListener('mouseover', squareOnMouseOver);
    });
  }
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(242, 239, 231);
    color: rgb(10, 10, 9);

}

.square{
    background-color: lightcoral;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(0deg);

    transition: all ease-out 0.5s;
    
}

.background {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container .row .col > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
  
.target {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#draw {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.name{
    font-size: 40px;
}

#main-container{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 35px 45px;

    width: 950px;
    height: 285px;

    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 2px rgb(191, 188, 182);

}

.links{
    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.icons{
    width: 55px;
    height: auto;

    margin: 0px 25px;
    padding: 10px;


    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

.icons:hover{
    background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
}

.refresh{
    position: absolute;
}

.refresh-button{
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="background">
    <div class="target"></div>
    <div class="container text-center" id="main-container">
        <div class="">
            <div class="refresh">
                <button class="btn" id="draw" onclick="drawSquares()"><img class="refresh-button" src="SVG/arrow-clockwise.svg"></button>
            </div>

            <div class="name">Berk Efe Keskin</div>
            <br>
            <i>This website is working in progress right now...</i>
            <br>
            <i>Here is some useful links.</i>
            <br>
            <br>
            
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#"><img class="icons" src="SVG/github.svg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="icons" src="SVG/linkedin.svg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="icons" src="SVG/stack-overflow.svg"></a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src = "javascript.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a function that given a container will be filled with how many squares can fit inside as long as there is still avaiable width and available height in the target.

Here in this demo I better factored your code and added a main function called `drawSquares` that gets called when the button `reDRAW` is clicked. Each time the squares are redrawn, the target content is emptied.

I'm using a button to trigger the box drawing because the available space depends on the size of the area when the action is fired. For example you can expand the snippet and decide to redraw the squares to have the whole new area filled again.

You may decide to call the action on document ready or when the window gets resized.

```js
let mouse = {
  speedX: 0,
  speedY: 0,
  posX: 0,
  posY: 0,
  movement: 0,
  speed: 0
}

//on mousemove update the moouse object
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  mouse.speedX = e.movementX;
  mouse.speedY = e.movementY
  mouse.posX = e.pageX;
  mouse.posY = e.pageY;
}

//refresh the mouse movement and speed every 100ms
setInterval(() => {
  mouse.movement =
    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouse.speedX, 2) + Math.pow(mouse.speedY, 2));
  mouse.speed = mouse.movement * 10;
}, 100);

//add a square div in parent element
function addSquare(parent) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("square")
  parent.appendChild(newDiv)
  return newDiv;
}

//add squares in the parent element filling the available size
//gap is the space between squares, size is the edge of the square
//if skipbefore is false it will begin to draw the next square also if it won't fit entirely
function addSquares(parent, gap, size, skipbefore = true) {

  const squares = [];

  let rect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  const availableWidth = rect.width;
  const availableHeight = rect.height;

  let top = 100;
  while (top < availableHeight) {
    let left = 0;
    if (skipbefore && top + size > availableHeight)
      break;
    while (left < availableWidth) {
      if (skipbefore && left + size > availableWidth)
        break;
      const square = addSquare(parent);
      square.style.left = `${left}px`;
      square.style.top = `${top}px`;
      squares.push(square);
      left += gap + size;
    }
    top += gap + size;
  }

  return squares;
}

//onmoveover event handler
const squareOnMouseOver = (event) => {
  const element = event.target;

  const y = mouse.speedY;
  const x = mouse.speedX;

  const rad = Math.atan2(y, x);
  yAxis = mouse.movement * Math.sin(rad);
  xAxis = mouse.movement * Math.cos(rad);

  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  const left = Math.round(rect.x + xAxis * 3);
  const top = Math.round(rect.y + yAxis * 3);

  element.style.left = `${left}px`;
  element.style.top = `${top}px`;
  const o = rad * (180 / Math.PI);
  element.style.transform = `rotate(${o}deg)`;
}

//resets the .target parent and redraw the squares inside it
function drawSquares() {

  const parent = document.querySelector('.target');
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  const squares = addSquares(parent, 25, 75);

  const colors = [
    'lightcoral',
    'bisque',
    'aquamarine',
    'cadetblue',
    'greenyellow',
    'yellowgreen'
  ];

  squares.forEach(square => {
    const iColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length - 1));
    const color = colors[iColor];
    square.style.background = color;
    square.addEventListener('mouseover', squareOnMouseOver);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.square {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all ease-out 0.5s;
}

#Header {
  font-size: italic;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.target {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#draw {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: .2em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .row .col > * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link el="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="background">

    <span>Work in progress...</span>

    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1 id="Header">Work in progress...</h1>
          <button id="draw" onclick="drawSquares()">reDRAW</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="target"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your help!

but... i have another problem with it.
I added some more styles on the main website and i want the squares stay behind 
but when i refresh the squares they spawn in front of the main divs i tried to but .target div on top of the main divs but it still seenable. Its fine if i cant move the squares behind the main div.

I will edit my question so you can see exactly what i was talking about.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Anyway in my answer for the style of the .target element I added `position:relative` and `z-index: -1`. Anyway probably you just was referring at the boxes when you said you wanted those to be behind. You could control the style of the boxes in milion ways.. including acting through the fact they can be easily selected with `.square` or any style can just be added directly in that ruleset

Comment: Ok I solved the problem..
i guess bootstrap gives a transparent look to .container element so i added a backgrond to it :D